# EXCEL - Unable to work out formula for weighting a population of customers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a population of customers which I need to weight as a percentage.

Example

Population is 1000.  Within the population 15% are English and 85% are Welsh.

25 of each gave birth late.  However I want to try and represent the real split.

i.e Not just 2.5% across the board.  I need a formula that shows it's 16.6% Welsh and 2.9% English.

Can anyone help?  It's racking my brain!

I have tried sum product but it's not given me the answer as the totals then don't add up.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is just simple math:

```
=25/(B1*A$1)
```

[image]